# How to run NUnit programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, assembly.load

I have some assembly that references NUnit and creates a single test class with a single test method. I am able to get the file system path to this assembly (e.g. "C:...\test.dll"). I would like to programmatically use NUnit to run against this assembly.

So far I have:

```
var runner = new SimpleTestRunner();
runner.Load(path);
var result = runner.Run(NullListener.NULL);
```

However, calling runner.Load(path) throws a FileNotFound exception. I can see through the stack trace that the problem is with NUnit calling Assembly.Load(path) down the stack. If I change path to be something like "Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" then I still get the same error.

I have added an event handler to AppDomain.Current.AssemblyResolve to see if I could manually resolve this type but my handler never gets called.

What is the secret to getting Assembly.Load(...) to work??

Comment: In the end my solution was to just use XUnit. NUnit is kind of crufty.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to open in a *console mode*, add **nunit-console-runner.dll** reference and use:

```
NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(new string[]
   {
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, 
   });
```

If you want to open in a *gui mode*, add **nunit-gui-runner.dll** reference and use:

```
NUnit.Gui.AppEntry.Main(new string[]
   {
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, 
      "/run"
   });
```

This is the best approach because you don't have to specify any path.

Another option is also to integrate NUnit runner in Visual Studio debugger output:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
    new TextUI (new DebugTextWriter()).Execute(new[] { assembly, "-wait" });
}

public class DebugTextWriter : StreamWriter
{
    public DebugTextWriter()
        : base(new DebugOutStream(), Encoding.Unicode, 1024)
    {
        this.AutoFlush = true;
    }

    class DebugOutStream : Stream
    {
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            Debug.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, offset, count));
        }

        public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
        public override bool CanSeek { get { return false; } }
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
        public override void Flush() { Debug.Flush(); }
        public override long Length { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); } }
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
        public override void SetLength(long value) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
        public override long Position
        {
            get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
            set { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it gives an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when calling Main. Perhaps different args are expected now?

Comment: If you're using the gui mode & nunit-gui-runner.dll, don't forget to mark your main func as [STAThread].

Comment: I just did the second example, GUI. I had to change `"/run"` to `"-run"`. I am running on Debian Gnu/Linux.

Comment: @Was Adding `[STAThread]` stopped be debugging local variable. removing it fixed this.

Comment: Hello, when I try to open the gui mode and I use code from your example, I have the following problem: first run ok, second run I get the error: "Object not set to an instance of an object". Analyzing the stack trace I founded that this error is raised inside nunit code. May be I should clean something after show the gui runner?

Answer (score 3):

"What is the secret to getting Assembly.Load to work?"

System.Reflection.Assembly.Load takes an string containing an assembly name, not a path to a file.

If you want to load an assembly from a file use:

```
Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToFileOnDisk);
```

(LoadFrom actually uses Assembly.Load internally)

By the way, is there any reason why you can;t use the [NUnit-Console command line tool](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.4) and just pass it the path to your test assembly?  You could then just use the System.Diagnostics.Process to run this from within your client application, might be simpler?

Comment: Well I wish I could use LoadFrom but unfortunately the Assembly.Load is being called from within NUnit not my code so I can't control it.

Comment: I probably will need to just call it through a process like you suggest... I would rather have objects for my own display purposes but it should be good enough to just use a process for now.

Comment: There are no 'secrets' in programming!