# How to run Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting unit tests programmatically?

Tags: c#-4.0, vs-unit-testing-framework

Suppose I have a unit test project UnitTests.dll:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        } 
    }
}
```

I would like to run the above unit tests programmatically from another project RunUniTests.exe. How do I do that? Something that's similar to NUnit counterpart such as the one shown in [How to run NUnit programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195061/how-to-run-nunit-programmatically) would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You can use command line to run it programmatically

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testmetadata:"vsmdiFile" /testsettings: